# Java JMeter DSL. How to execute custom logic in threadGroup() method?

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter

The problem: I need to execute UI autotests in the performance tests. Need to look at how many users can open the Web page and do some requests exactly from this page (performance test on the API is not enough).

So I use Java JMeter DSL for the performance testing.
I have the next code:

```
TestPlanStats stats = testPlan(
            threadGroup(
                    testParams.getThreads(), Duration.ofMinutes(testParams.getLoadTime()),
                    myCustomLogic
            ).rampTo(testParams.getThreads(), Duration.ofMinutes(testParams.getRumpUpTime())),
            influxDbListener(envSetting.getInfluxDbUrl())
                    .measurement("ui-performance")
    ).run();
```

**The question is**: how to implement **myCustomLogic** in the threadGroup for execution of UI tests for each thread in the performance test?

For example, I already tried to put jsr223Sampler() with the script on Groovy.

I have an implementation of UI autotest with the needed logic (open web page and other actions)

```
public class ApiSteps {

public void doSomeLogic() {
    //do some actions
}
```

}

and put this script like this:

```
        String script = "Object apiStepsInstance = new ApiSteps();" +
            "vars.putObject(\"apiSteps\", apiStepsInstance)" +
            "def apiSteps = vars.getObject(\"apiSteps\")\n" +
            "apiSteps.doSomeLogic()";
    DslJsr223Sampler dslJsr223Sampler = new DslJsr223Sampler("UI performance test", script);
    dslJsr223Sampler.language("Groovy");
    TestPlanStats stats = testPlan(
            threadGroup(
                    testParams.getThreads(), Duration.ofMinutes(testParams.getLoadTime()),
                    dslJsr223Sampler
            ).rampTo(testParams.getThreads(), Duration.ofMinutes(testParams.getRumpUpTime())),
            influxDbListener(envSetting.getInfluxDbUrl())
                    .measurement("ui-performance")
    ).run();
```

In the script, I tried to call the **apiSteps.doSomeLogic()** java method.

Tell me please if this is a successful way to put Groovy script with calling java method please correct my script.

If the way of putting this Groovy script is wrong, please provide the way how can I do UI autotests during performance testing.

Thanks a lot for the answers.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like valid and correct way of running Groovy code using JMeter Java DSL

At least if you do something like:

```
testPlan(
        threadGroup(1,
                1,
                new DslJsr223Sampler("UI performance test", "println('Hello from JSR223')")))
        .run();
```

You should see `Hello from JSR223` message in [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)):

[image]

Most probably if you need to run your custom class you need to add it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (along with any [dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)) like [here](https://github.com/abstracta/jmeter-java-dsl/blob/master/jmeter-java-dsl/src/main/java/us/abstracta/jmeter/javadsl/core/engines/JmeterEnvironment.java#L45)

You can check out [Groovy code debug](https://github.com/abstracta/jmeter-java-dsl/issues/41#issuecomment-966715062) ticket for some hints.

More information: [JMeter DSL: Bringing Performance Testing Closer to Developers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-dsl)

Answer (score 0):

As Dimitri mentioned, the general approach looks ok.

I only want to point out that if you want to use a ramp up and then hold for duration, you should use something like this:

```
threadGroup()
  .rampToAndHold(testParams.getThreads(), Duration.ofMinutes(testParams.getRumpUpTime()), Duration.ofMinutes(testParams.getLoadTime())),
  .children(dslJsr223Sampler)
```